# how to test android with ormlite project

Tags: android, junit, ormlite

anyone could help me with the problem: how to test android apps which uses ormlite?

I'd like to know how to create mocks form dao. This code gets me a dao

```
public Dao<Account, Integer> getAccountDao() throws SQLException {
    if (accountDao == null) {
        accountDao = getDao(Account.class);
    }
    return accountDao;
}
```

My testing activity looks this:

```
public class OrmActivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initUi();
        initUiListeners();

        RuntimeExceptionDao<Account, Integer> accountDao = getHelper().getAccountDataDao();
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setName("name");
        account.setPassword("password");
        accountDao.create(account);
    }
```

I dont want to create separate database for tests. Instend of it I want to use mocks.

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this post.  The issue I had was that you need an instance of an Activity so you can pass the context to the **OpenHelperManager.getHelper(android.content.Context context, Class openHelperClass)** method.

To get around this I create a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test class to provide the context.  You could use **MockContext** but I understand it to be problematic.  This way is simple stupid, sort of :)

At that point I don't bother testing any of the Activity functionality, just database functionality.

```
public class TestActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainFragment> {

    public TestActivity() {
        super(MainFragment.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        //DatabaseHelper.class is the extended OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class
        OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testDetailDiscount() {
    //Example code using an entity class that encapsulates ormlite functionality 
        double total = 95 * 5;
        DocumentDetail detail = DocumentDetail.create(getActivity());
        assertEquals(total, detail.getTotal());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I use Robolectric for unit testing Android apps. Works fine with RoboGuice and Ormlite. Robolectric creates its own database, so a unit test doesn't modify the database on the device you are testing with.

If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify your question. Like, how is not using a separate database related to using mock dao's?

Comment: @christine - do you a sample code of roboelectric and ormlite working together

Comment: @Christine can you put the link here so anyone can find?